# call a java program from c program in linux

Tags: java, c, linux, centos, javac

On a CentOS 7 server, I have a java program `/path/to/parent/bin/mainpackage/SendText.class` that works perfectly when I call it from a c program located at `/path/to/parent/bin` using the syntax:

```
system("java -cp .:\"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*\" mainpackage.SendText username pincode");
```

But the problem is that the c program cannot be located in `/path/to/parent/bin`.  Instead, the c program must be located in `/path/to/parent/`.  **How can I change the syntax so that the java program will run when called from `/path/to/parent/`?**

Here is what I have done to set things up so far:

The java program was compiled from `/path/to/anotherparent/` using the command

```
javac -d bin -cp .:/path/to/anotherparent/dependencies/twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar:/path/to/anotherparent/dependencies/httpcore-4.1.2.jar SendText.java
```

I then created the destination and copied SendText.class and its dependencies to the destination as follows:

```
[user@domain somedir]$ mkdir /path/to/parent/bin/
[user@domain somedir]$ mkdir /path/to/parent/bin/mainpackage
[user@domain somedir]$ sudo cp /home/username/javacode/bin/mainpackage/SendText.class /path/to/parent/bin/mainpackage
[user@domain somedir]$ sudo mkdir /path/to/parent/dependencies
[user@domain somedir]$ sudo cp -R /home/username/javacode/dependencies/* /path/to/parent/dependencies
```

Next, I created the c program `atest.c` in `/path/to/parent/` as follows:

```
[user@domain somedir]$ cd /path/to/parent
[user@domain parent]$ sudo nano atest.c

int main (void){
    char jcmd[256] = "java -cp .:\"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*\" mainpackage.SendText username pincode";
    printf(jcmd);
    system(jcmd);
    return 0;
}

Ctrl-X to save the program
```

I compiled the c program and tried to run it from `/path/to/parent/` as follows:

```
[user@domain parent]$ sudo cc atest.c -o atest
[user@domain parent]$ ./atest
Error: Could not find or load main class mainpackage.SendText
java -cp .:"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*" mainpackage.SendText username pincode
```

To confirm that the problem is the location of the c file, I did the following:

```
[user@domain parent]$ sudo cp atest bin
[user@domain parent]$ cd /path/to/parent/bin
[user@domain bin]$ ./atest
```

Program runs successfully from `/path/to/parent/bin`

**So what do I change in order to get the java program to run successfully when it is called from `/path/to/parent/` with the command `./atest`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javac -d bin ...
```

That means that `bin`, as an absolute path, must appear in the CLASSPATH when you run it. Better still, create a JAR file for the contents of `bin`, put it whenever you like, and provide the absolute path of the JAR file as a CLASSPATH element when you execute.